# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que por ejemplo un div baje conforme el usuario desplaza la página hacia abajo?

Tags: html, css

Os pongo en contexto, tengo una web conformada por un iframe, un header y un footer. He insertado el iframe en la web, como si el contenido del iframe fuese el original de la web.
Entonces, quiero hacer que si por ejemplo deslizo hacia abajo el contenido del iframe (en mi caso un div) baje también ese div. No sé si me he explicado, pero aquí os dejo los codes.
Un saludo.

HTML (Web que contiene el iframe):

```
<iframe class="iframito" src="./assets/loading/load.php" width="1200" height="400"> </iframe>
```

HTML Iframe:

```
<div class="advise" id="advised" onclick="hide_d()">
    
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>    <div class="helper_ad">     <span class="shout"><span class="but"> .</span> Prueba    </span></div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS Iframe:

```
    /*Importation of google font OP*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap');

.advise {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5%;
    background-color: #D14021;
    position: fixed !important;
    right: 1px;
    top: 2px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}


.shout {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 567px;
    word-spacing: 0.25em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.helper_ad{
    margin-top: 7px;

}


/*   Media query of phone, (advise)   */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 786px) {
.helper_ad{
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: 63px;

}
.advise{
    height: 3.6%;
}
    .fa-exclamation-circle{
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 13px;
        margin-left: 20px;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle un estilo con CSS y utilizar la propiedad `position : fixed` la cual "fijará" el contenido mientras te desplazas por tu página